# Blur effect in a view of iOS

Tags: ios, camera, preview, blur, effect

I want to use an UIImagePicker to have a camera preview being displayed. Over this preview I want to place an overlay view with controls.

Is it possible to apply any effects to the preview which will be displayed from camera? I particularly need to apply a blur effect to the camera preview.

So I want to have a blurred preview from camera and overlay view with controls. If I decide to capture the still image from the camera, I need to have it original without blur effect. So blur effect must applied  only to the preview.

Is this possible using such configuration or maybe with AVFoundation being used for accessing the camera preview or maybe somehow else, or that's impossible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With AV foundation you could do almost everything you want since you can obtain single frame from the camera and elaborate them, but it could lead you at a dead-end applying a blur on an image in realtime is a pretty intensive task with laggy video results, that could lead you to waste hours of coding. I would suggest you to use the solution of James WebSster or OpenGL shaders. Take a look at this awesome free library written by one of my favorite guru Brad http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework even if you do not find the right filter, probably it will lead you to a correct implementation of what you want to do.
The right filter is Gaussian blur of course, but I don't know if it is supported, but you could do by yourself.

Almost forgot to say than in iOS 5 you have full access to the Accelerate Framework, made by Apple, you should look also into that.

Comment: By the way, as far as I know, apps using third party frameworks are not allowed for adding to AppStore, right?

Comment: No, you can use it fortunately (-: . The rejection is about app that uses private APIs. The only thing that you should do is check the license with the dev has released the library, maybe it requires attribution or something else.

Comment: Oh, I dodn't know that. Thank you for the link. Looks really interesting.

Comment: And may I apply OpenGL shaders to the method with UIPickerController?

Comment: Actually no, you need spare frames from the camera, AVFoundation is the way to go, I think that in the sample of GPUImgeFramework you could find a nice starting point without doing so much effort.

Comment: @BartoNaz - As an FYI, there's no blur filter in the stock filters right now, but I will be adding a Gaussian blur by Keitaroh Kobayashi this afternoon. I haven't benchmarked it yet, so I can't speak to the performance of the first version of this filter, but we should be able to tune it to run in realtime on all supported iOS devices.

Comment: By the way, did somebody see Microsoft's Photosynth. I have noticed that its camera preview is reacting to movement much smoother than the original one in Camera app (at least in indoor light). It seems not using the automatic exposure correction. What they could use for that? Also AVFoundation?

Comment: @BartoNaz - As an update, I've added a GPUImageFastBlurFilter to GPUImage, which does a heavily optimized 9-hit Gaussian blur to images. It can filter a 640x480 video frame in under 2 ms on an iPhone 4, so it's more than fast enough to blur in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

From the reasonably limited amount of work I've done with UIImagePicker I don't think it is possible to apply the blur to the image you see using programatic filters.

What you might be able to do is to use the overlay to **estimate** blur. You could do this, for example, by adding an overlay which contains an image of semi-transparent frosted glass.

Comment: And do there exist any filters or whatever that can blur everything that is under it?

Comment: *by adding an overlay which contains an image of semi-transparent frosted glass.* for example