# what is the best approach to a convolution shader in OpenGL ES 2 that is fast enough for realtime?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, shader

**NOTE:** Right now I'm testing this in the simulator. But the idea is that I get acceptable performance in say, an iPhone 4s. (I know, I should be testing on the device, but I won't have a device for a few days).

I was playing around with making a convolution shader that would allow convolving an image with a filter of support 3x3, 5x5 or 7x7 and the option of multiple passes. The shader itself works I guess. But I notice the following:

1. A simple box filter 3x3, single-pass, barely blurs the image. So to get a more noticeable blur, I have to do either 3x3 2-pass or 5x5.
2. The simplest case (the 3x3, 1-pass) is already slow enough that it couldn't be used at say, 30 fps.

I tried two approaches so far (this is for some OGLES2-based plugins I'm doing for iPhone, that's why the methods):

```
- (NSString *)vertexShader
{

    return SHADER_STRING
    (
     attribute vec4 aPosition;
     attribute vec2 aTextureCoordinates0;

     varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates0;

     void main(void)
     {
         vTextureCoordinates0 = aTextureCoordinates0;
         gl_Position = aPosition;
     }

     );
}

- (NSString *)fragmentShader
{
    return SHADER_STRING
    (
     precision highp float;

     uniform sampler2D uTextureUnit0;
     uniform float uKernel[49];
     uniform int uKernelSize;
     uniform vec2 uTextureUnit0Offset[49];
     uniform vec2 uTextureUnit0Step;

     varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates0;

     void main(void)
     {
         vec4 outputFragment = texture2D(uTextureUnit0, vTextureCoordinates0 + uTextureUnit0Offset[0] * uTextureUnit0Step) * uKernel[0];
         for (int i = 0; i < uKernelSize; i++) {
             outputFragment += texture2D(uTextureUnit0, vTextureCoordinates0 + uTextureUnit0Offset[i] * uTextureUnit0Step) * uKernel[i];
         }

         gl_FragColor = outputFragment;
     }

     );
}
```

The idea in this approach is that both the filter values and the offsetCoordinates to fetch texels are precomputed once in Client / App land, and then get set in uniforms. Then, the shader program will always have them available any time it is used. Mind you, the big size of the uniform arrays (49) is because potentially I could do up to a 7x7 kernel.

**This approach takes .46s per pass.**

Then I tried the following approach:

```
- (NSString *)vertexShader
{

    return SHADER_STRING
    (
     // Default pass-thru vertex shader:
     attribute vec4 aPosition;
     attribute vec2 aTextureCoordinates0;

     varying highp vec2 vTextureCoordinates0;

     void main(void)
     {
         vTextureCoordinates0 = aTextureCoordinates0;
         gl_Position = aPosition;
     }

     );
}

- (NSString *)fragmentShader
{
    return SHADER_STRING
    (
     precision highp float;

     uniform sampler2D uTextureUnit0;
     uniform vec2 uTextureUnit0Step;
     uniform float uKernel[49];
     uniform float uKernelRadius;

     varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates0;

     void main(void)
     {
         vec4 outputFragment = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);
         int kRadius = int(uKernelRadius);
         int kSupport  = 2 * kRadius + 1;
         for (int t = -kRadius; t <= kRadius; t++) {
             for (int s = -kRadius; s <= kRadius; s++) {
                 int kernelIndex = (s + kRadius) + ((t + kRadius) * kSupport);
                 outputFragment += texture2D(uTextureUnit0, vTextureCoordinates0 + (vec2(s,t) * uTextureUnit0Step)) * uKernel[kernelIndex];
             }
         }

         gl_FragColor = outputFragment;
     }

     );
}
```

Here, I still pass the precomputed kernel into the fragment shader via a uniform. But I now compute the texel offsets and even the kernel indices in the shader. I'd expect this approach to be slower since I not only have 2 for loops but I'm also doing a bunch of extra computations for every single fragment.

**Interestingly enough, this approach takes .42 secs.** Actually faster...

At this point, the only other thing I can think of doing is braking the convolution into 2-passes by thinking of the 2D kernel as two separable 1D kernels. Haven't tried it out yet.

Just for comparison, and aware that the following example is a specific implementation of box filtering that is A - pretty much hardcoded and B - doesn't really adhere to theoretical definition of a classic nxn linear filter (it is not a matrix and doesn't add up to 1), I tried this approach from the OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming guide:

```
- (NSString *)fragmentShader
{
    return SHADER_STRING
    (
     // Default pass-thru fragment shader:
     precision mediump float;

     // Input texture:
     uniform sampler2D uTextureUnit0;

     // Texel step:
     uniform vec2 uTextureUnit0Step;


     varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates0;

     void main() {
         vec4 sample0;
         vec4 sample1;
         vec4 sample2;
         vec4 sample3;
         float step = uTextureUnit0Step.x;
         sample0 = texture2D(uTextureUnit0, vec2(vTextureCoordinates0.x - step, vTextureCoordinates0.y - step));
         sample1 = texture2D(uTextureUnit0, vec2(vTextureCoordinates0.x + step, vTextureCoordinates0.y + step));
         sample2 = texture2D(uTextureUnit0, vec2(vTextureCoordinates0.x + step, vTextureCoordinates0.y - step));
         sample3 = texture2D(uTextureUnit0, vec2(vTextureCoordinates0.x - step, vTextureCoordinates0.y + step));
         gl_FragColor = (sample0 + sample1 + sample2 + sample3) / 4.0;
     }
     );
}
```

**This approach takes 0.06s per pass.**
Mind you, the above is my adaptation where I made the step pretty much the same texel offset I was using in my implementation. With this step, the result is very similar to my implementation, but the original shader in the OpenGL guide uses a larger step which blurs more.

So with all the above being said, my questions is really two-fold:

1. I'm computing the step / texel offset as vec2(1 / image width, 1 / image height). With this offset, like I said, a 3x3 box filter is barely noticeable. Is this correct? or am I misunderstanding the computation of the step or something else?
2. Is there anything else I could do to try and get the "convolution in the general case" approach to run fast enough for real-time? Or do I necessarily need to go for a simplification like the OpenGL example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run those through the OpenGL ES Analysis tool in Instruments or the Frame Debugger in Xcode, you'll probably see a note about [*dependent texture reads*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW15) -- you're calculating texcoords in the fragment shader, which means the hardware can't fetch texel data until it gets to that point in evaluating the shader. If texel coordinates are known going into the fragment shader, the hardware can prefetch your texel data in parallel with other tasks, so it's ready to go by the time the fragment shader needs it.

You can speed things up greatly by precomputing texel coordinates in the vertex shader. Brad Larson has a good example of doing such in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481351/957768) to a similar question.

Comment: you mean just the texel offsets or the whole thing including the offset + the original texture coords? I tried just the offsets in the vertex shader but didn't see any improvement. at 0.06s that is still not fast enough for real time (assuming 30fps I'd have about 1/30 to process each frame).

Comment: To put it a different way: If the texcoord parameter to `texture2D` is the result of *any computation done in the fragment shader*, it'll be slow. That includes adding an offset computed in the vertex shader. If you do all your texcoord calculations in the vertex shader, as in the answer I linked, you should see much-improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answers regarding your precise questions, but you should take a look at [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework - which implements several box blur filter (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466502/blur-effect-in-a-view-of-ios)) - among which a 2-pass 9x9 filter - you can also see this article for real-time FPS of different approaches : [vImage VS GPUImage vs CoreImage](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/01/blur-effect-in-ios-applications/?lang=en)

Comment: I'll take a look at the article thanks!. I did check out the code for GPUImage yesterday and the approach to box blurring is pretty much the one from my last example taken from the OpenGL ES 2 Programming Guide. Still not fast enough for realtime :/